# error reading the response :Invalid XML error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, ajaxform

I m checking if username exists in the database using ajax with php& mysql. The browser is throwing the following error in the popup:

> error reading the response: Invalid XML

[image]

My `HanleServerResponse()` function:

```
function handleServerResponse() {
    // retrieve the server's response packaged as an XML DOM object
    var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;

    // catching potential errors with IE and Opera
    if (!xmlResponse || !xmlResponse.documentElement)
        throw("Invalid XML structure:\n" + xmlHttp.responseText);

    // catching potential errors with Firefox
    var rootNodeName = xmlResponse.documentElement.nodeName;
    if (rootNodeName == "parsererror")
        throw("Invalid XML structure:\n" + xmlHttp.responseText);

    // getting the root element (the document element)
    xmlRoot = xmlResponse.documentElement;

    // testing that we received the XML document we expect
    if (rootNodeName != "response" || !xmlRoot.firstChild)
        throw("Invalid XML structure:\n" + xmlHttp.responseText);

    // the value we need to display is the child of the root <response> element
    responseText = xmlRoot.firstChild.data;

    // display the user message
    myDiv = document.getElementById("myDivElement");
    myDiv.innerHTML = "Server says the answer is: " + responseText;
}
```

My ajax.php file:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");

    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT fname FROM users WHERE fname='$username';");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $name = $row['fname'];
        if ($name == $username) {   
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $response = $dom->createElement('response');
            $dom->appendChild($response);
            $text = $dom->createTextNode('username exits');
            $response->appendChild($text);
            $xml_string=$dom->saveXML();
            echo $xml_string;
        } else {
            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $response = $dom->createElement('response');
            $dom->appendChild($response);
            $text = $dom->createTextNode('username available');
            $response->appendChild($text);
            $xml_string=$dom->saveXML();
            echo $xml_string;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the response of the ajax request? You also are open to SQL injections with this code; don't pass user input direct to your query.

Comment: you are right I m not using mysql_escape_string as I am just testing ajax. It will be better if you can solve the above error .

Comment: You ignored the first part of my comment? **What is the response of the ajax request?**

Comment: If username already exits in database then response is "username exits" else "available"

Comment: Are you looking at the request in the developer's console? http://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art034

Comment: nope, I am not looking in developers console. I dont know whats the problem with xml because it is showing error in XML . :(

Comment: It might be that there is a 500 on your PHP page so XML isn't being returned. Check the response of the request, also look at the response if it is a 200.

Comment: XML is returned with response 'username exits' if  I enter a username which is already stored in the database but when I enter a username which is not stored in database then the above error(shown in image) is shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it might give others a clue to solving the problem.

The code snippets that OP posted appear to work as expected. The PHP generates an xml response and the Javascript is able to extract the value. The only way to duplicate the reported error was by mangling the xml, such as by adding a leading space. OP might try adding a "ob_end_clean();" statement to the PHP part to clear the response buffer of any extraneous output (best guess). And seeing the full XMLHttpRequest would be helpful in troubleshooting.

OP's code tests for a name in the database and returns one of these responses:

match:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>username exits</response>
```

no match:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>username available</response>
```

Both responses were tested by feeding them to DOMParse to generate an xml document:

```
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlResponse = parser.parseFromString( strXml,"text/xml");
```

No errors were observed. Next, the xml was fed to OP's function *handleServerResponse()*.  It returned the correct value in both cases.

Comment: maybe using **ob_end_clean();** will do some good because most of the books have used it.